# svg: указание относительный координат, аналогичных calc()

Tags: svg, position, позиционирование, relation

Приветствую

Подскажите, есть ли возможность в svg указывать относительные координаты с возможностью довычисления, например:

20 точек от конца

```
<use xlink:href="#node" x="calc(100% - 10)" y="0" />
```

или еще более сложные рассчёты

```
<use xlink:href="#node" x="10 + (100% - 2 * 10) / (8 - 1) * 5" y="0"/>
```

Если нет, то получается, что располагать элементы svg относительно размеров окна практически невозможно :(

Простой пример:
есть элемент #node, размером 20, который должен располагаться по координатам:

```
10,
10 + 100% / 11
10 + 1.5 * 100% / 11
10 + 4.5 * 100% / 11
10 + 9.0 * 100% / 11
```

...

Comment: Тоже очень интересен этот вопрос. Возможно есть какие-то JS фреймворки для этого?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я же не 100% в сети, сейчас прочитаю везде ответы, везде отвечу